# API function call not working in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch-api

My function to fetch data from API not working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Contact extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this)
    }

    fetchData(){
        let base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/'
        fetch(base_url, {method:"GET"})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                data:json
            })
        })

        console.log(this.state.data)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Contact page{this.state.data.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Contact
```

Comment: Please add more details, like the errors message that you get etc

Comment: Probably you have to use map function, because your state "data" is array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you haven't called the `fetchData` function anywhere. Call it within `componentDidMount` method

Secondly data is supposed to be an array so `this.state.data.title` will throw you can error

Lastly state updates are reflected in the next render cycle and hence logging `console.log(this.state.data)` will not show you the updated data

```js
    class Contact extends React.Component{
    
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state = {
                data: []
            }
            this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this)
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
           this.fetchData();
        }
    
        fetchData(){
            let base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/'
            fetch(base_url, {method:"GET"})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    data:json
                })
            })
    
        }
    
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Contact page</h1>
                    {this.state.data.map(photo => <div>{photo.title}</div>)}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Contact/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```